# Wanting to call a class instead of plain text while in the stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I want to call a class but it needs to happen in the stylesheet already.

With @keyframes I've created a rotation ticker for my website that right now displays plain text. Instead I need it to show live updated footballresults from games being played that day.

I have in the background a lot of code working to ensure that I do in fact have those live results. Right now those are being displayed in a sidebar, all together at the same time.

In my script I have for that a call to a function like the following:

```
<script>
        loadSingleMatchData('3325736', 'match1', 1, ' URL ', 1); 
</script>
```

In my sidebar I then call for that by adressing a class:

```
<body>
<div id="match1"></div>
</body>
```

That already works perfectly and does what it must. As I said, I also want to display that data in a newsticker above the page. For that I wrote the following code:

```
<style>
.vwrap {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #eee;
 height: 30px;
 display:flex;
 align-items: center;
     
}
.vitem {
   padding:10px;
}  
   
.vitem:before {
 opacity:0;
    content: "Speeldag 5"
animation-name: replacement;
animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-direction: absolute;
}
 
@keyframes replacement {
 0%{
opacity: 1;
}
 10%{
   opacity:0;
 }
 12.5%{
   content: "match2" ;
   opacity:1;
 }
 22.5%{
   opacity:0;
 }
 25%{
   content:"match3";
   opacity:1;
 }
 35%{
   opacity:0;
 }
 37.5%{
   content:"match4";
   opacity:1;
 }
 47.5%{
   opacity:0;
 }
 50%{
   content:"match5";
   opacity:1;
 }
 60%{
   opacity:0;
 }
 62.5%{
   content:"match6";
   opacity:1;
 }
 72.5%{
   opacity:0;
 }
 75%{
   content:"match7";
   opacity:1;
 }
 85%{
   opacity:0;
 }
 87.5%{
   content:"match8";
   opacity:1;
 }
 97.5%{
   opacity:0;
 }
 100%{
   opacity:0;
 }

}  
</style>


<div class="vwrap">
   <div class="vitem">    
       
   </div>
</div>

<script>
        loadSingleMatchData('3325736', 'match1', 1, ' URL ', 1); 
        loadSingleMatchData('3325583', 'match2', 1, ' URL ', 1);  
        loadSingleMatchData('3325728', 'match3', 1, ' URL ', 1);
        loadSingleMatchData('3325668', 'match4', 1, ' URL ', 1);
        loadSingleMatchData('3325632', 'match5', 1, ' URL ', 1);
        loadSingleMatchData('3325667', 'match6', 1, ' URL ', 1);  
        loadSingleMatchData('3325590', 'match7', 1, ' URL ', 1);
        loadSingleMatchData('3325650', 'match8', 1, ' URL ', 1);
</script>
```

And this is where I am stuck. As you can see I'm declaring the content in the stylesheet and there I can only place plain text. How do I change that plain text to the call `<div id=match1></div>`